# Write node details to IPFS

Tags: networking, bootnode, multiaddress, rust-ipfs

I want to write the [`multi-addresses`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sc_rpc/system/trait.SystemApiServer.html#tymethod.system_local_listen_addresses) of all nodes in my network to a file on the IPFS. I see that there's [this](https://github.com/TDSoftware/substrate-ipfs/tree/master/frame/tds-ipfs) module that can be used to write data to IPFS, I was just wondering whether it would be possible for a node that as soon as it becomes part of the network, its multiaddress is written to IPFS? Are there any possible issues that I can face in the process?